# Pasting tables from a webpage kept the formatting, but now pasting tables is only in plain text

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-office

I copy and pasted a table from an online page to a Word document, and the formatting pasted perfectly.

I repeated the process several times (there are many tables on the same page online), but now it will not allow me to paste the table. It will only paste the plaint text from the table, without the formatting/grid as it did before.

This was all in one day from the same page - nothing different. I even tried to copy and paste the same tables that had worked before - but they all fail to paste the table now. Did I accidentally click something by mistake and turn off the paste properties?

Answer (score 1):

Try following the instructions from [this Microsoft support article](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Control-the-formatting-when-you-paste-text-20156a41-520e-48a6-8680-fb9ce15bf3d6). It's possible your default paste options got changed somehow. You're looking to keep original formatting:

> **Preserve the look of the original text**
>
> The text that you move or copy can have a font or other kind of
>   formatting applied to it, such as bold or italic, that differs from
>   the document where you are pasting the text. For example, you can move
>   or copy text that is bold, 10-point Times New Roman, and paste it next
>   to text that is regular, 11-point Calibri. If you want the pasted text
>   to be in Times New Roman instead of Calibri, you can preserve its
>   look.
>
> 1. Select the text that you want to move or copy, and then press CTRL+X to move the text, or press CTRL+C to copy the text.
> 2. Click where you want to paste the text, and then press CTRL+V.
> 3. Click the Paste Options button  [image], which appears after you paste the text.
>
> If you don't see a Paste Options button, press CTRL+Z to undo the
>   paste, and then turn on the option for displaying it. For procedures,
>   go to [Turn on the Paste Options button](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Control-the-formatting-when-you-paste-text-20156a41-520e-48a6-8680-fb9ce15bf3d6#turnonpaste).
>
> 4. Click Keep Source Formatting.